# Lambda Explaination

Tags: python, lambda

I was reading [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/why-are-python-lambdas-useful) and I found the [following example code](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) in the Python documentation, but I don't fully understand how the result is produced.

**Example:**

```
>>> def make_incrementor(n):
...     return lambda x: x + n
...
>>> f = make_incrementor(42)
>>> f(0)
42
>>> f(1)
43
```

What I don't fully understand is how the number 42 gets increased to 43 when `x` isn't set inside the function.

From my understanding every call to `f` is like calling a new instance of the method, but it doesn't behave that way.

**Questions:**

1. Why is the first call to `f` done like this: `f = make_incrementor(42)` but the other calls aren't ?
2. How does `x` get set so that every number passed to the function as an argument gets added to it?

Comment: When you call `f = make_incrementor(42)`, it assigns the following function: `lambda x: x + 42`, to `f`

Comment: Because you have a function that returns a function.

Comment: try `f = lambda x: x + 42` and then `f(0)`, `f(1)`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941 this is the correct original question here.